# Call function from string in nodejs

Tags: string, node.js, function, window, global

What is the equivalent to window[my_func_name] in nodejs? I'm reading a string from stdin and if it's a function name I want to execute it. I thought global[my_func_name] might work but unfortunately it doesn't.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It works just fine

```
global.foo = function foo () {
  console.log("foo was called");
}

process.stdin.on("data", function(input) {

  // don't forget to call .trim() to remove the \n
  var fn = input.toString().trim();

  // function exists
  if (fn in global && typeof global[fn] === "function") {
    global[fn]();
  }

  // function does not exist
  else {
    console.log("could not find " + fn + " function");
  }
});

process.stdin.resume();
```

Output

```
foo
foo was called
bar
could not find bar function
```

**Whether or not this is a good idea...** well, that's an entirely different discussion.

---

**EDIT** — ≈18 months later... Yeah, it's a **horrible** idea to call a global function like that.

In saying that, here's *one* way you could approach the problem in a much better way. Below we're going to build a little [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) (read-eval-print loop). In order to understand it better, I'll break it down into a couple parts.

First, we want to make sure our REPL waits for the user to press enter before we try running their command. To do that, we'll create a [transform stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform) that waits for a `"\n"` character before sending a `line` down the pipe

> The code below is written using [ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_6_support_in_Mozilla). If you're having trouble finding a compatible environment to run the code, I suggest you check out [babel](http://babeljs.io/).

```
// line-unitizer.js
import {Transform} from 'stream';

class LineUnitizer extends Transform {
  constructor(delimiter="\n") {
    super();
    this.buffer = "";
    this.delimiter = delimiter;
  }
  _transform(chunk, enc, done) {
    this.buffer += chunk.toString();
    var lines = this.buffer.split(this.delimiter);
    this.buffer = lines.pop();
    lines.forEach(line => this.push(line));
    done();
  }
}

export default LineUnitizer;
```

Don't get too hung up on `LineUnitizer` if you're new to stream processing and it doesn't quite make sense. This kind of stream transform is extremely common. The general idea is this: once we pipe `process.stdin` into a receiving stream, `process.stdin` will be emitting data every time the user presses a key. However, our `Repl` (implemented below) can't act on a command until the user has *finished* typing the command. `LineUnitizer` is the part that waits for the user to press enter (which inserts a `"\n"` into the stream) and then signals to `_transform` that the command is ready to be sent to `repl` for processing!

Let's look at `Repl` now

```
// repl.js
import {Writable} from 'stream';

class Repl extends Writable {
  _parse(line) {
    var [cmd, ...args] = line.split(/\s+/);
    return {cmd, args};
  }
  _write(line, enc, done) {
    var {cmd, args} = this._parse(line.toString());
    this.emit(cmd, args);
    done();
  }
}

export default Repl;
```

Well hey, that was easy! What does it do tho? Each time `repl` receives a line, it emits an event with some args. Here's a visual way to see how a command is parsed

```
The user enters       emit event      args
-------------------------------------------------------------
add 1 2 3             "add"           ["1", "2", "3"]
hens chocobo cucco    "hens"          ["chocobo", "cucco"]
yay                   "yay"           []
```

Ok, now let's wire everything together to see it work

```
// start.js
import LineUnitizer from './line-unitizer';
import Repl         from './repl';

process.stdin
  .pipe(new LineUnitizer())
  .pipe(
    (new Repl())
      .on("add", function(args) {
        var sum = args.map(Number).reduce((a,b) => a+b, 0);
        console.log("add result: %d", sum);
      })
      .on("shout", function(args) {
        var allcaps = args.map(s => s.toUpperCase()).join(" ");
        console.log(allcaps);
      })
      .on("exit", function(args) {
        console.log("kthxbai!");
        process.exit();
      }));
```

Run it

```
$ node start.js
```

Output

> Lines prefixed with `>` are user input. The `>` will not actually be visible in your terminal.

```
> add 1 2 3
add result: 6
> shout I can see it in your face!
I CAN SEE IT IN YOUR FACE!
> exit
kthxbai!
```

---

If you think that's awesome, we're not even done yet. The benefits of writing our program this way is that we can act on the commands regardless of how they arrive at our program.

Consider this `commands.txt` file

```
add 100 200
shout streams are the bee's knees
exit
```

Now run it like this

```
$ cat commands.txt | node start.js
```

Output

```
300
STREAMS ARE THE BEE'S KNEES
kthxbai!
```

---

Ok, so that's pretty fricken great. Now consider that the commands could come from anywhere. Could be a database event, something across the network, a CRON job, etc. Because everything is nicely separated, we could easily adapt this program to accept a variety of inputs with ease.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I just thought a global function would automatically be added to the global object as is the case with the window object.

Comment: @PaulK, for what it's worth, I've written many complex node.js apps and I've never (even *once*) touched `global`

Comment: Thanks, however there is an error in your code. You need to replace the "function exists" to:
`if (fn in global && typeof global[fn] === "function") {`
Your test fails at "fn" is a string, and you test if it is a function.

Comment: @PaulK I've made a significant improvement to the above answer. I hope this helps you solve similar problems in an effective manner **^.^**

Answer (score 15):

Write your functions in a separate file and export them and use with name reference of that to call them, Like

```
//    functions.js
var funcOne = function(){
                   console.log('function ONE called')
              }
module.exports={
    //  name_exported : internal_name
    funcOne : funcOne
}
```

Use function defined in *functions.js* in index.js :

```
//    index.js
var methods = require('./functions.js')   // path to functions.js
methods['funcOne']()
```

OUTPUT :

```
> node index.js
> function ONE called
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var theTests = require('./tests'); 
//@TODO CaseID should be caseId
var CaseID = 5678;
// use dynamic functions
var functionName = 'theTests.TEST_' + CaseID;
var functionString = String('TEST_' + CaseID);

var check = eval( 'typeof ' + functionName ); // bad
if ( check == 'function' ) {
    // run the function
    // testResult = eval( functionName ); nope
    testResult = theTests[functionString](); //yep :)
    console.log(testResult);
}
else {
    console.log( 'No test functions for ' + CaseID );
}
```

in this example in tests.js 
will be looking for...

```
TEST_5678: function(){
     return some thing;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Came across this with the same question myself, and I'm a newbie too, so take this with a grain of salt - from other [posts here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849136/does-node-js-have-equivalent-to-window-object-in-browser) mentioning the `global` object, I also discovered that `module` seems to be the local object in Node.js, on which `exports` are defined.

So if you have in a module:

`exports.myFunction = myFunction;`

And at some point, after you've declared the export (you can write your exports at the top of the file/script, even before you've declared myFunction()), you call:

`module.exports['myFunction']()`

That will essentially call `myFunction()`

Again, newbie, so take with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 0):

This does **not** answer the PO question **directly**,
still it's a way to call a function based on it's string name manually.

I wanted to achieve something like this

where **I knew the arguments beforehand**

It is for a pre-configured script.

`npm run $function_name`

so I decided to go this way.

Let's say you have implemented some functions named : fun1, fun2, fun3

Store them inside an object:

```
const RUNNERS = { fun1, fun2, fun3 };
```

Create one file (or many) containing the args (in my case is 1 but works for more), like this:

args.ts

```
export const args = {
 arg1: 3,
 arg2: "string",
 arg3: { propA: "hey"},
};
```

Create a driver function like this:

```
/**
 * Called from terminal like this
 *
 * npm run {fun1|fun2|fun3}
 * @param runner The function to run - Set internally
*/
const driver = async runner => await runner(args)
```

In package.json create a script:

```
"fun1": "RUNNER=fun1 npm start"
```

And call driver function like this

```
driver(RUNNERS[process.env.RUNNER])
```

This sets the name of the function internally, but you can pass it yourself to the npm script as an environment variable as well.
You can also programmatically over-write the arguments you need based on their keys (names) as well, or through env

The only caveat here is that you must destructure the correct args for each function yourself plus its a bit messy for hard typing eg:

fun1 may only use args.arg1,
fun 2 may only use args.arg2 and args.arg3 etc..

This will do the trick

```
const fun1 = async({ arg1 }: { [key: string]: any }) => { ... }

const fun2 = async({ arg2, arg3 }: { [key: string]: any }) => { ... }
```

You can call it from terminal like this

```
npm run fun1
```

**Hope this will help someone with some modifications**