# Does node.js have equivalent to window object in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js

What I mean is does node.js have object that are global function methods of. Like this in browser:

```
function myGlobalFunction() {
    console.log(this === window);
}
myGlobalFunction();

=> true
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The closest equivalent in node is `global`. I'm not sure if it translates in all of the same ways, but if you open a REPL and type in `this === global`, it will return true.

Here's a discussion on the global object, though some it the information may be deprecated as it's pretty old: ['Global' object in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133114/global-object-in-node-js)

Comment: this === global will only return true inside of a REPL. If you are actually executing a script file like node myScript.js it will be false.  See this post for an explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336759/global-variable-assignment-in-node-from-script-vs-command-line

Answer (score 26):

Yes, the [`global`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) variable is the global object in Node.js

From the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global):

> global# {Object} The global namespace object. In browsers, the
>   top-level scope is the global scope. That means that in browsers if
>   you're in the global scope var something will define a global
>   variable. In Node this is different. The top-level scope is not the
>   global scope; var something inside a Node module will be local to that
>   module.