# Self-invoking argument changing this to undefined in babel-loader

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I am using Webpack with babel-loader, and i see this trouble: babel-loader change `this` agrument in anonymous self-invoking functions to `undefined` instead `this`.

In example:

```
(function (t1, t2) {
})(this, 'test')
```

Convert to:

```
(function (t1, t2) {
})(undefined, 'test');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Babel assumes that every file is a (ES2015) module. A module's `this` has the value `undefined` at runtime. To simulate the correct behavior in environments that don't support modules yet (every environment at this time), Babel replaces every top level `this` with `undefined`.

Comment: After further reading, this is the correct answer. For reference, [here is Babel's official explanation](https://github.com/babel/babel.github.io/blob/862b43db93e48762671267034a50c30c00e433e2/docs/faq.md#why-is-this-being-remapped-to-undefined).

Comment: @MikeC: Ah, you found the FAQ, thanks. It seems it's not linked anymore on the actual page.

Comment: It's not linked because "plugins" should be used instead. However, how to solve this issue for e.g. self-invoking functions?

Comment: @julmot: I don't understand what you mean. What's the issue you want to solve?

Comment: I would like to know a solution for this issue, not just the background information. Assuming you are using the es2015 preset this issue will occur. How to you prevent babel from replacing `this` with `undefined`? This is especially a problem if you are having a plugin exposure for e.g. AMD or CommonJS and you are passing `this` as a reference for the global environment to a self-invoking function.

Comment: @julmot: Assuming I understand you correctly, why not explicitly pass `window` in that case? I don't think there is a generic solution. But if the general question is "how to reference the global object", I'd use `global` and let my module bundler or another transform take care of substituting it with the right reference.

Comment: @FelixKling I am open for changes but using `this` and not `window` is the popular way of doing it. In NodeJS there is no `window`, but a `global`. So using `this` will work in both variants, in browsers it will mean `window` and in NodeJS it will mean `global`. [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849136/does-node-js-have-equivalent-to-window-object-in-browser)

Comment: @julmot: not quite. `this` inside a node module does not refer to the global object. It either refers to `module` or `exports` (not sure right now). Besides, I'd argue that using the global object in Node is rather an anti-pattern.