# thisArg of array.forEach does not reference as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach, object-reference

Given following code:

```
const theArray = ['Audi','Volvo','Mercedes'];

const myObj = {a: 7};

theArray.forEach((value, index, array) => {
    console.log(index + ' : ' + value);
    console.log(array === theArray);
    console.log(this.a);
}, myObj);
```

I get following output:

```
0 : Audi
true
undefined
1 : Volvo
true
undefined
2 : Mercedes
true
undefined
```

Where I don't understand why `this` does not reference myObj and returns undefined instead of 7.
While `this typeof Object` returns true, I don't know which Object it references. I just know that `this` returns an empty Object(i.e. {})

Node.js interpreter version is v6.2.1

V8-Engine version is 5.0.71.52

Comment: An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and lexically binds the this value (does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target). Arrow functions are always anonymous. source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: It is working if you are removing the arrow function https://jsfiddle.net/t9sbfv5a/

Comment: @NinaScholz, What is the solution ?

Comment: If you need to define thisArg you should use the older `function () {}` syntax.

Comment: Arrow function always lexically bound to this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Problem**

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An **arrow function expression** has a shorter syntax compared to [function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) and lexically binds the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) value (does not bind its own [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), [`super`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super), or [`new.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target)). Arrow functions are always [anonymous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name).

**Solution 1**

Use `function`

```js
const theArray = ['Audi','Volvo','Mercedes'];

const myObj = {a: 7};

theArray.forEach(function (value, index, array) {
    console.log(index + ' : ' + value);
    console.log(array === theArray);
    console.log(this.a);
}, myObj);
```

**Solution 2**

Use a closure

```js
var abc = 'abc';
const theArray = ['Audi','Volvo','Mercedes'];

const myObj = {a: 7};

theArray.forEach((obj => (value, index, array) => {
    console.log(index + ' : ' + value);
    console.log(array === theArray);
    console.log(obj.a);
    console.log(this.abc);
})(myObj));
```

Comment: Thanks, totally missed that point about arrow functions. So in my example, this refers to the object which encloses the forEach loop. (So this must be a/the global object which is just empty?)

Comment: `this` refers to the windows object.

Comment: Ok I think in node.js, there is no window object, maybe because it does run on the server and not in the browser. I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849136/does-node-js-have-equivalent-to-window-object-in-browser) which states that in node.js there is a Object global which is the closest to the window object. :) Just in case you are interested.

Comment: @MMike Node.js replaces the `window` with `process`. This acts as the global object with similar functionality to what you'd find in `window` on the browser. https://nodejs.org/api/process.html

Comment: @ooronning `process` is not the global object like `window` is, `global` is. `process` is a global variable / property of `global` (and the `root` and `GLOBAL` aliases).

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Well then. Heh. Was totally unaware that `process` was a property of `global`. I was under the impression, though, that `process` takes on more of the functionality of `window`. Incorrect?

Comment: @ooronning In some respects. The standard global JavaScript API's are available through `global`. `process` holds all the Node extensions. So you might think of it being like `document`, but it's really it's own thing.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Thank you for your clarification.