# React/ES6: Arrow Function not binding "this" as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, leaflet, arrow-functions

Language: React/JavaScript ES6

Bundling Tool: Webpack(babel-loader 6.0.0)

Other Libs Involved : Leaflet

**Problem:**

With the function below the context `this` is bound to the
component as I need.

**Before:**

```
componentDidMount: function() {

     map.on('draw:created', function(e){
        this.setState({someProp:propUpdate});
        featureGroup.addLayer(e.layer);
     }.bind(this));

    }
```

But when I switched it over to using the arrow function I expected
an equivalent binding, but `this` changed to a leaflet Class
`o.Class.extend.e` - leaving `this.setState` undefined.

**After:**

```
componentDidMount: function() {

    map.on('draw:created', (e) => {
        this.setState({someProp:propUpdate});
        featureGroup.addLayer(e.layer);
    });

}
```

Question: Why is using the arrow function not the equivalent of 
binding `this` in my case?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127635/thisarg-of-array-foreach-does-not-reference-as-expected/

Comment: @Rayon that example of arrow functions in a ```forEach``` loop doesn't give any clues why my async callback is losing binding scope. Are you suggesting "lexical binding" is different from es5 binding?

Comment: Don't you get `window` as this if you `log` it ?

Comment: No the context changed to ```o.Class.extend.e```

Comment: Which is the same as ```e``` strangely enough. I was expecting it to be ```ReactClass.createClass.Constructor```

Comment: Seems like a bug in your environment / transpiler. Although Babel should work fine. The code itself looks fine. I doubt we can help much if we cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: So far I think @FelixKling is probably right. "react": "^0.14.0", "webpack": "^1.12.1", "babel-core": "^6.6.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0"

Comment: Try upgrading to the latest version of babel.

Comment: @FelixKling Updated all babel stuff(babel-cli for server-side rendering, babel-loader for webpack, babel-core for goodluck, babel-polyfill for object assign, and all the babel-presets) I then updated webpack to the current version. Still the issue. :(

Comment: Can you show us the transpilation result, please?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Turns out the Babel-loader (in my case using the preset '@babel/preset-env') does not bind the arrow function to this as one would expect.

Using this plugin in my webpack config added the correct binding

```
plugins: [
  ['@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions', { 'spec': true }]
]
```