# What is 'this' defined to in the node shell?

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

This is my script in a file named `foo.js`.

```
console.log(this === module.exports)
```

This gives the expected output, i.e. `true`.

```
$ node foo.js
true
$ node
> require('./foo')
true
{}
```

But I am unable to understand why the following produces the opposite output, i.e. `false`.

```
$ node
> console.log(this === module.exports)
false
undefined
> .load foo.js
> console.log(this === module.exports)
false
undefined
```

What is `this` defined to in the node shell?

Comment: global object, `global`

Comment: You probably should have tried typing `this` in the console and pressing enter. :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does node.js have equivalent to window object in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849136/does-node-js-have-equivalent-to-window-object-in-browser)