# Why does node print undefined and the browser doesn't?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I run this code in node, the function foo prints `undefined`. But if I run the same code in the Chrome or Firefox console I get the right output (`oops, global`). Can anyone clarify why?

```js
function foo() {
  console.log(this.a);
}
function doFoo(fn) {
  // `fn` is just another reference to `foo`
  fn(); // <-- call-site!
}
var obj = {
  a: 2,
  foo: foo
};
var a = "oops, global"; // `a` also property on global object
doFoo(obj.foo); // "oops, global"
```

Comment: Is your question about what gets returned, or what gets printed by `console.log()`?

Comment: in the global scope in a browser, `var a = ...` is like `window.a = ...` - and this in foo is window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In browsers, global variables become properties of the `window` object. And when a function is called without a context, the context also defaults to the `window` object. Since you're calling `foo()` without supplying a context, `this.a` is treated as `window.a`, which is the global variable.

Node.js has a global object called `global`, but global variables are not made properties of that object. See [Does node.js have equivalent to window object in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849136/does-node-js-have-equivalent-to-window-object-in-browser). `this.a` is treated as `global.a`, but this is undefined because the variable declaration doesn't assign to it.