# Access Environment Variables from SASS in Next.JS

Tags: webpack, sass, environment-variables, next.js

I am trying to add a variable to my `scss` files, referenced to `.env` variable. To achieve this, I've read a few tutorials, and I found [this](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#additionaldata). I need to add this configuration to my `next.config.js`

```
const withImages = require('next-images');

module.exports = withImages({
    webpack(config, options) {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: "css-loader",
                    options: {
                        importLoaders: 2,
                        modules: {
                            compileType: 'module'
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                    options: {
                        additionalData: `$cdnURL: '${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CDN_URL}';`
                    }
                }
            ]
        })
        return config
    }
})
```

As you can see, I remove the `style-loader`, because I am getting [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53951861/window-is-not-defined-error-when-using-style-loader-with-webpack). So when I remove this, I am able to proceed. I was able to add the environment variable; however, I am overriding the default `scss configuration` of `next`. So whenever I am trying to build my project, I got this `warning`:

```
Warning: Built-in CSS support is being disabled due to custom CSS configuration being detected.
See here for more info: https://err.sh/next.js/built-in-css-disabled
```

The application is running, but the `scss` was not bundled as a module I believe.

So is there anyway wherein I can add my `environment variable` to `scss` without overriding `next.js` configuration as a whole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding an additional configuration for `sass-loader` you need to modify the built in one.

There is no ***official*** way to modify it yet, but the `config` that is passed to you contains the default, all you need to do, is to search for the specific loader and modify it.

This example is based on **Next.js v9.5.2**. Instead of using `additionalData`, you need to use `prependData` since that is what on the `API Schema` of `sass-loader`

```js
config.module.rules
  .filter((rule) => !!rule.oneOf)
  .forEach((rule) => {
    rule.oneOf
      .filter((oneOfRule) => {
        return oneOfRule.test
          ? oneOfRule.test.toString().includes('sass') &&
              Array.isArray(oneOfRule.use) &&
              oneOfRule.use.some((use) => use.loader.includes('sass-loader'))
          : false;
      })
      .forEach((rule) => {
        rule.use = rule.use.map((useRule) => {
          if (useRule.loader.includes('sass-loader')) {
            return {
              ...useRule,
              options: {
                ...useRule.options,
                prependData: `$cdnURL: '${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CDN_URL}';`,
              },
            };
          }
          return useRule;
        });
      });
  });
```

On **Next.js v9.5.4 and later**, you should use `additionalData`.

Comment: Add a few amendments to your code, but the base and the logic is still there. Basically, not all the `oneOfRule` variable has `test` property, so I needed to check first. And the `additionalData` is not part of the interface of `option` of `sass-loader`, so I needed to change it to `prependData`, and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Update the answer for **Next.js v9.5.4**