# How to configurate webpack to build react components library with css-modules for Next.js application?

Tags: webpack, next.js, react-css-modules

**Background**

Hi!

I develop a components library and I have to build it to import in another project. So, I configurated webpack and tried to import a random component and got SSR error:

> Server Error ReferenceError: document is not defined
>
> Call Stack
>
> insertStyleElement
>
> node_modules/lib/dist/index.js (367:14)

Of course code (after build) below raises error in nextjs app. Its internal *style-loader* function.

```
function insertStyleElement(options) {
  var style = document.createElement('style');
  ...
}
```

**Configs**

[All configs are here](https://gist.github.com/NooNoo1337/0b9a299a1f50c15169910ddb19575fda)

**Stacks**

Lib stack:

- React
- TypeScript
- css-modules + postcss

Main App stack:

- TypeScript
- Nextjs

**Question**

I suppose that trouble comes from style-loader (insertStyleElement is exporting from there). Where did I make mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is not about webpack loaders. You try to call document.createElement but there is no document/window space on the server (you are able to work with it only in the browser).

You need to add helper inside your library:

```
export const isClient = () => typeof window !== 'undefined';
```

And then you can use it like:

```
var style = isClient() && document.createElement('style');
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I know about isClient helper but I dont use the document object in code. insertStyleElement is the loader internal function so I cant use something like isClient helper.

Comment: Oh, sorry. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53951861/window-is-not-defined-error-when-using-style-loader-with-webpack Suppose it can help.

Comment: Thx. I fixed my issues with extracting css with MiniCssExtractPlugin. i will try another methods but MiniCssExtractPlugin did the trick.